# Find the average of 2 elements in Arrays.asList using Java stream()

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I have trouble with finding the average between two integers in an `Arrays.asList` including different data types (Strings and Integers). Is it possible to use streams in such a case?

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    String faculty;
    private final int groupNumber;
    private final int commonSubjectGrade;
    private final int specialSubjectGrade;

    public Student(String name, String faculty, int groupNumber, int commonSubjectGrade, int specialSubjectGrade){
    this.name = name;
    this.faculty = faculty;
    this.groupNumber = groupNumber;
    this.commonSubjectGrade = commonSubjectGrade;
    this.specialSubjectGrade = specialSubjectGrade;
}

public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
          
    public int getCommonSubjectGrade() {
        return commonSubjectGrade;
    }

    public int getSpecialSubjectGrade() {
        return specialSubjectGrade;
    }
}
```

I need find the average between two last integers (commonSubjectGrade & specialSubjectGrade).

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
static List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
        new Student("Podrick Payne", "IntrigueFaculty",1, 7, 8),
        new Student("Margaery Tyrell", "IntrigueFaculty", 1, 4, 9),
        new Student("Sandor Clegane", "IntrigueFaculty", 1, 8, 8),
        new Student("Eddard Stark", "IntrigueFaculty",1, 9, 6),
        new Student("Petyr Baelish", "IntrigueFaculty",1, 5, 8)
);

public static void main(String[] args) {
        double averageGradeForCommonSubject = students.stream().mapToDouble(Student::getCommonSubjectGrade).average().getAsDouble();
        System.out.println("Average grade in common subject for the entire university = " + averageGradeForCommonSubject);
}
```

The first part (finding the average in the common subject among all the students) works good but the next does not :(

```
double averageGradeOfTheCertainStudent = students.stream().filter((student) -> student.getName().equals("Petyr Baelish")).
                mapToDouble(student -> student.getSpecialSubjectGrade() & student.getCommonSubjectGrade()).average().getAsDouble();
System.out.println("Average grade of Petyr Baelish = " + averageGradeOfTheCertainStudent);
```

What is the method to calculate the average for the last 2 integers for Petyr Baelish (between 8 & 5)?
I'll appreciate any help. Please do not laugh at me if my question is stupid. I have been learning Java just for 3 weeks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close!

You are looking for `flatMap`.

We can `flatMap` a student to a stream of 2 grades, then get the average of the stream.

Also, as mentioned, it's better to map to `Integer` (as grades are `int`).

```
double averageGradeOfTheCertainStudent = students.stream()
        .filter(student -> student.getName().equals("Petyr Baelish"))
        .flatMapToInt(student -> IntStream.of(student.getSpecialSubjectGrade(), student.getCommonSubjectGrade()))
        .average()
        .getAsDouble();
```

Output:

```
Average grade of Petyr Baelish = 6.5
```

Comment: @Shubt I think this will help - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Following my question how can I find the same average if the method `getSpecialSubjectGrade()` is in the class `Student` (as super class) and the method `.getCommonSubjectGrade()` is in the Student's sub class? How can I reach this sub class method using `.flatMapToInt` (or any else)? I had to add sub class and override one method and the solution you suggested was broken :( Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Shubt I don't understand. Do you keep a list of the super class?

Comment: At the very beginning I had the only class `Student` with 2 class fields `int commonSubjectGrade` and `int specialSubjectGrade` (and getters). I tryed to find the average between them. Then I created sub class `StudentOfTheGroup extends Student` removing the field `int specialSubjectGrade` from class `Student` to sub class `StudentOfTheGroup`. And now the calculation of the average does not work because `.flatMapToInt` now can use only the getter of the class `Student` (`getCommonSubjectGrade()`). I can't reach to the second getter (`getSpecialSubjectGrade()`).

Comment: So you keep a `List<Student>` and some of its objects are just `Student` and some are also `StudentOfTheGroup`?

Comment: Right you are. List remained the same. But the objects in the list are from different classes (super and sub classes)

Comment: `List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(`  
`new StudentOfTheGroup = ("Petyr Baelish", 8, 5)` but 8 belongs to `Student` and 5 to `StudentOfThe Group`

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you can do:

Comment: students.stream().filter((student) -> student.getName().equals("Petyr Baelish")).flatMapToInt(student -> { if(student instanceof StudentOfGroup){ StudentOfGroup studentOfGroup = (StudentOfGroup)student;return IntStream.of(studentOfGroup.getSpecialSubjectGrade(), student.getCommonSubjectGrade()); } else{ return IntStream.of(student.getCommonSubjectGrade()); } }).average().getAsDouble();

Comment: Perhaps a better approach will be to create a `calculateAverage() `method on the superclass and override it in sub-class. then you will be able to call it from `map()`

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's a bit complicated for me but it's work! I wouldn't have found such a solution by myself. Tomorrow I'll try to digest your code but tonight it's impossible for me :) Thank you once again! Tomorrow I will also try to use suggested `calculateAverage()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `&` for finding the average. This operator is used for bit-wise AND operation.

Find the sum of the required fields and then divide it by 2 to find the average.

```java
double avg = students.stream()
                     .filter(student -> student.getName().equals("Petyr Baelish"))
                     .mapToDouble(student -> student.getSpecialSubjectGrade() + student.getCommonSubjectGrade())
                     .map(i -> i/2)
                     .findFirst()
                     .orElse(0d);
System.out.println("Average grade of Petyr Baelish = " + avg);
```